# Выборка данных из двух полей

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблицы

1. `types` с полями `name, keyid`
2. `phones` с полями `keyid, typeid, pname, status`

значения поля `status` = 0 и 1 (0 - старый, 1 - новый)

Как мне вывести запросом данные в виде

```
Тип // Новый // Старый // Количество
```

Например так:

```
Тип                   Новые         Старые    Количество
Смартфоны             5             6         11
Обычные телефоны      2             3         5
```

Comment: Если записей "новый" и "старый" не более одной каждого типа (для одного keyid) то сделать два раза left join телефонов к типам, и прямо в условиях ON соединения указать для одной status=0, и 1 для другого.

Comment: Запись всегда одна, может измениться статус

Comment: можно пример небольшой? не очень поняла мысль

Comment: Если запись одна, то что в колонках "новый' и "старый"

Comment: Нет вы не поняли. Записей вообще много, куча. Я имею ввиду запись с уникальным keyid одна. У такой записи меняется лишь поле status

Comment: понятно что записей много. вы просите что бы в выборке были колонки тип, новый, старый и количество. тип это я так понимаю и есть этот самый keyid (ну или имя его), но вот что должно быть показано в остальных трех колонках я не понимаю

Comment: Аа поняла.. В колонке Новый количество телефонов по каждому типу, в колонке Старые тоже количество телефонов по каждому типу. В вопрос добавила вид как мне нужно

Comment: А, ну тогда просто join двух таблиц а на выводе `sum(1-status) "Старые", sum(status) "Новые", ...` ну и group by по типу

Comment: а что делает sum(1-status) ?

Comment: если status=1, то `1-status` равен 0. А если он 0, то `1-0` равен единице. таким образом мы суммируем единички у тех строк, у которых нулевой статус

Comment: А если вдруг status = 2 или 3? я тут смотрю есть и такие записи

Comment: Я читаю ваш вопрос, там сказано: "_значения поля status = 0 и 1 (0 - старый, 1 - новый)_". Это как бы предполагает, что других быть не может. Тогда пишите явно проверку на те или иные значения с помощью case или decode. Или отфильтруйте в where только интересующие записи

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
with types(name, keyid)
as
(
    select 'AAA', 1 from dual
    union all
    select 'BBB', 2 from dual
    union all
    select 'CCC', 3 from dual
),
phones(keyid, typeid, pname, status)
as
(
    select 1, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual
    union all
    select 1, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual
    union all
    select 1, 0, 'Текст', 1 from dual
    union all
    select 1, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual
    union all
    select 2, 0, 'Текст', 1 from dual
    union all
    select 2, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual 
    union all
    select 3, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual
    union all
    select 3, 0, 'Текст', 1 from dual
    union all
    select 3, 0, 'Текст', 0 from dual
    union all
    select 3, 0, 'Текст', 1 from dual 
)
-- Ваш запрос:
select
name,
sum(old),
sum(new),
count(status)
from
    (select
    t.name, 
    decode(p.status, 0, 1, 0) old,
    decode(p.status, 1, 1, 0) new,
    p.keyid,
    p.status 
    from 
    types t
    join
    phones p
    on p.keyid = t.keyid)
group by name 
order by 1
```